# In auto populate i have two dropdown related with each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In auto populate i have two drop down..one value is category fetched from database and another i show the subcategory of selected category. i use on change option to get subcategory.

On editing on change not working i think because category is not changed.. How i get the sub category value without changing the category but use previous code event on change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#category').on('change',function(){
        var mainID = $(this).val();
        if(mainID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'functions/ajaxlocation.php',
                data:'cat_id='+mainID,
                success:function(html){
                   $('#location').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#location').html('<option value="">Select Category first</option>');
        }
})
```

Comment: Try it :- data:{cat_id:mainID}

Comment: This code is working man.. i want a code when i edit the record and i get the category value from database and make it already selected  but sub category value not come because i use on change but category is already selected

Comment: then you already know the sub category id so populate sub category dropdown with subcategory id.